# Strings' Comparison

Tags: java

I have two Strings "Hello" and "Hello World" and program should return longest string "Hello World". I thought that I need to write with compareTo() but it returns number, not the String. How can I return the biggest string?

Comment: string.length() is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can try someting like this, and compare the lengths:

```
       public String max(String string1, String string2) {
           return (string1.length() > string2.length()) ? string1 : string2;
       }
```

---

Or if you want your code to be more readable instead of using ternary operator you can write it as following:

```
if(string1.length() > string2.length())
  return string1;
else if(string1.length() < string2.length()
  return string2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to compare the strings and retrieve only the longest one, then it's enough to compare only their lengths:

```
public static String getLongestString(String one, String two) {
    return one.length() >= two.length() ? one : two;
}
```